# Merging two strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
a = '---e'
b = 'e---'

for i in a:
  c=''
  for k in b:
    if i == k:
        c += i
    else:
        c += '-'


print(c)
```

Result:

```
e---
```

I wanted to merge a and b so that the result would be 'e--e'. Can this be done using for loops? Can someone please fix my code or suggest a different approach.  I'd prefer to use the for loop if possible.

Thanks

Update:

Thanks to 'poke' and his explanation of the zip function, i came up with a working code:

```
a = '---e'
b = 'ee-e'
c = ''
for x,y in zip(a,b):
  if x != '-':
    c += x
  else:
    c += y
```

print(c)

Output:

```
ee-e
```

Comment: You only merge if the two characters are the same; merge instead if they are *not* equal, pick the one that is not equal to `-`. You are also testing the *product* of the two strings, instead of pairing up the characters. E.g. you compare the first character of `a` with *every character in `b`. Then the second character of `a` is compared with *every character in `b`.

Comment: What would happen for two strings `e---` and `f--e`?

Comment: Note that in each iteration of the outer loop, you're resetting `c` back to an empty string, therefore only the last iteration will have any effect on the final value.

Comment: You're just providing a test case, what's the general rule for "merging" two strings?

Comment: You should break loop after c += i and c='' should be outside for loop.

Comment: I'm trying to write a function for a larger program. The string is produced in a while loop. The string is dynamic, it changes with every loop.  So, i'm trying to update the string after every loop. I hope that's comprehensible.

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not. It's not important that how do you build them, just please say given two strings s1 and s2 how do you merge them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility, taking the character from the first string, unless that one is `-`:

```
>>> a = '---e'
>>> b = 'e---'
>>> ''.join(x if x != '-' else y for x, y in zip(a, b))
'e--e'
```

This works by first zipping the two strings. That way, each character is paired with the character from the other string at the same location. So we get a list of pairs:

```
>>> list(zip(a, b))
[('-', 'e'), ('-', '-'), ('-', '-'), ('e', '-')]
```

We then iterate over that list, taking each element of the pair as `x` and `y`. So we now just need to apply our rule to choose one of those two. In the above case, I use `x` unless it’s equal to `'-'`:

```
x if x != '-' else y
```

Then all those individual characters are collected and joined to get a string back.

Comment: Thanks for the zip function explanation.  I was able to rewrite using for loop. The code is more readable.